# The limit of the Harmonic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose $\lim x_n=a$, then the fact is that the limit of arithmetic mean series and geometric mean series of this series are also $a$. i.e. $\lim \frac{a_1+...+a_n}{n}= a$ and $\lim \sqrt [n] {a_1·...·a_n}= a$. Then how about the harmonic series of the original series?

Is this true?:  $\lim \frac{n}{\frac{1}{a_1}+...+\frac{1}{a_n}}= a$?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is also true if $a_n\ne 0$ and $a \ne 0$. Apply the arithmetic mean property to the sequence $b_n = \frac 1{a_n}$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs.